# extracting upper and lower row if a condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Regards.
I have the following coordinate dataframe, divided by blocks. Each block starts at seq0_leftend, seq0_rightend, seq1_leftend, seq1_rightend, seq2_leftend, seq2_rightend, seq3_leftend, seq3_rightend, and so on. I would like that, for each block given the condition if, coordinates are negative, extract the upper and lower row. example of my dataframe file:

```
seq0_leftend  seq0_rightend
0              7         107088
1         107089         108940
2         108941         362759
3         362760         500485
4         500486         509260
5         509261         702736
seq1_leftend  seq1_rightend
0              1         106766
1         106767         108619
2         108620         355933
3         355934         488418
4         488419         497151
5         497152         690112
6         690113         700692
7         700693         721993
8         721994         722347
9         722348         946296
10        946297         977714
11        977715         985708
12       -985709        -990725
13        991992        1042023
14       1042024        1259523
15       1259524        1261239
seq2_leftend  seq2_rightend
0              1         109407
1         362514         364315
2         109408         362513
3         364450         504968
4        -504969        -515995
5         515996         671291
6        -671295        -682263
7         682264         707010
8        -707011        -709780
9         709781         934501
10        973791        1015417
11       -961703        -973790
12        948955         961702
13       1015418        1069976
14       1069977        1300633
15      -1300634       -1301616
16       1301617        1344821
17      -1515463       -1596433
18       1514459        1515462
19      -1508094       -1514458
20       1346999        1361467
21      -1361468       -1367472
22       1369840        1508093
seq3_leftend  seq3_rightend
0              1         112030
1         112031         113882
2         113883         381662
3         381663         519575
4         519576         528317
5         528318         724500
6         724501         735077
7         735078         759456
8         759457         763157
9         763158         996929
10        996931        1034492
11       1034493        1040984
12      -1040985       -1061402
13       1071212        1125426
14       1125427        1353901
15       1353902        1356209
16       1356210        1392818
seq4_leftend  seq4_rightend
0              1         105722
1         105723         107575
2         107576         355193
3         355194         487487
4         487488         496220
5         496221         689560
6         689561         700139
7         700140         721438
8         721458         721497
9         721498         947183
10        947184         978601
11        978602         986595
12       -986596        -991612
13        994605        1046245
14       1046247        1264692
15       1264693        1266814
```

Finally write a new csv with the data of interest, an example of the final result that I would like, would be this:

```
seq1_leftend  seq1_rightend
11        977715         985708
12       -985709        -990725
13        991992        1042023
seq2_leftend  seq2_rightend
3         364450         504968
4        -504969        -515995
5         515996         671291
6        -671295        -682263
7         682264         707010
8        -707011        -709780
9         709781         934501
10        973791        1015417
11       -961703        -973790
12        948955         961702
14       1069977        1300633
15      -1300634       -1301616
16       1301617        1344821
17      -1515463       -1596433
18       1514459        1515462
19      -1508094       -1514458
20       1346999        1361467
21      -1361468       -1367472
22       1369840        1508093
seq3_leftend  seq3_rightend
11       1034493        1040984
12      -1040985       -1061402
13       1071212        1125426
seq4_leftend  seq4_rightend
11        978602         986595
12       -986596        -991612
13        994605        1046245
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have a **list** of DataFrames, let's call it *src*.

To convert a **single** DataFrame, define the following function:

```
def findRows(df):
    col = df.iloc[:, 0]
    if col.lt(0).any():
        return df[col.lt(0) | col.shift(1).lt(0) | col.shift(-1).lt(0)]
    else:
        return None
```

Note that this function starts with reading column *0* from the source
DataFrame, so it is independent of the name of this column.

Then it checks whether any element in this column is *< 0*.

If found, the returned object is a DataFrame with rows which
contain a value *< 0*:

- either in this element,
- or in the previous element,
- or in the next element.

If not found, this function returns *None* (from your expected result
I see that in such a case you don't want even any empty DataFrame).

The first stage is to collect results of this function called on each
DataFrame from *src*:

```
result = [ findRows(df) for df in src ]
```

An the last part is to filter out elements which are *None*:

```
result = list(filter(None.__ne__, result))
```

To see the result, run:

```
for df in result:
    print(df)
```

For *src* containing first 3 of your DataFrames, I got:

```
    seq1_leftend  seq1_rightend
11        977715         985708
12       -985709        -990725
13        991992        1042023
    seq2_leftend  seq2_rightend
3         364450         504968
4        -504969        -515995
5         515996         671291
6        -671295        -682263
7         682264         707010
8        -707011        -709780
9         709781         934501
10        973791        1015417
11       -961703        -973790
12        948955         961702
14       1069977        1300633
15      -1300634       -1301616
16       1301617        1344821
17      -1515463       -1596433
18       1514459        1515462
19      -1508094       -1514458
20       1346999        1361467
21      -1361468       -1367472
22       1369840        1508093
```

As you can see, the resulting list contains only results
originating from the second and third source DataFrame.
The first was filtered out, since *findRows* returned
*None* from its processing.